# How to remove __MACOSX folder in a list of zip files (not a single zip file)?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, command-line, zip

I know I can remove __MACOSX in a zip file by:

```
sudo zip -d bg1.zip "__MACOSX*"
```

but I want to remove it in all zip files, I tried

```
sudo zip -d *.zip "__MACOSX*"
```

but it says

```
zip warning: name not matched: __MACOSX*

zip error: Nothing to do! (bg1.zip)
```

and seems stop from processing next file. How can I remove all __MACOSX in a list of zip files?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`? Is that necessary? Are all the `.zip` files in the same directory?

Answer (score 4):

If all `.zip` files are in the same directory, `cd` to that *directory* and use:

```
for f in *.zip; do zip -d "$f" "__MACOSX*"; done
```